# turn a div into a link in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I apply the following to a div in rails so that when you click on the div it functions just like this link? Thanks

```
<%= link_to "#2", :class => "xtrig", :rel => "coda-slider-1" %>
```

Comment: What's the HTML code you are expecting Rails to generate?

Answer (score 11):

I may be misunderstanding you but...

If you want the div to be a clickable link, the logical solution is to write something that generates

```
<a href="#2">
  <div>
    Some stuff
  </div>
</a>
```

However, this is bad as putting block elements inside inline elements is wrong.

link_to can accept a block, so you could use spans:

```
<%= link_to('#2') do %>
  <span>Some stuff</span>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively a Javascript handler on the div onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to "link name", :anchor => "#2", :class => "xtrig", :rel => "coda-slider-1" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have a block element in a separate line you do not need a `<div>` but you can make the `<a>` tag "behave like a div":

```
a.xtrig {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails provide link_to block to wrap the html code inside it and make them clickable.

```
<%= link_to(your_path) do %>
  Entire html code written inside will be clickable.
<% end %>
```